# Size of square changes upon adding text

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="square1"></a>
```

The css corresponding to that is:

```
a.square1
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 9%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

When I try to put text inside of it, the size of the square changes. How can I avoid that?

Comment: give a `display:block;` in your css.....

Comment: @Sarbaz gave that,, still didn't get. Can I see a demo please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your anchor element is not square. Giving `width: 50%` and `height: 50%` doesn't make it square. It just calculates the width and height of the element related to its parent element. You should provide fixed values instead of percentage values. and also convert the inline anchor element to block element by using `display: block`.

```
a.square1
{
    width: 100px;      /* fixed value */
    height: 100px;     /* fixed value */
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 9%;
    display: block;    /* converted to block element */
    margin-top: 0%;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/qgLt2yLf/)**

The layout seems to be responsive square element because of padding value in percentage, because padding top or bottom values in percentages are respective to width instead of height.

**Note**: You can also use `vh`/`vw` units (*works in modern browsers*). The fallback for using is that it will work whether with width resizing or height resizing, but not for both dimensions resizing.

For example:

```
width: 20vh; height: 20vh; //works for height resizing
```

and

```
widdth: 20vw; height: 20vw; //works for width resizing
```

Comment: didn't get what you are saying. My anchor element is a square and in that I want to add texts.Giving fixed values won't make it responsive so I gave percentage values. Can u show in fiddle what are u trying to say?

Comment: @AshaDevyani `width: 50%` will be relative to the width of the screen and `height: 50%` will be relative to height of the screen. I am sure your monitor screen is not square. So, giving values in percentage will not give you element in square. and also you should mention `display: block` to make the inline anchor element act as block element (_then only width and height will apply_). Check the fiddle in updated post.

Comment: @AshaDevyani check the fiddle. It is still responsive.

Comment: @Mr-Green thanks a lot. You saved my day. i owe u a date now.. hahaha

Answer (score 0):

When I made a few test websites; the buttons sizes (without any editing whatsoever) were mainly dependant on the length, and font-size of the text. You may need to change the text's font to fix this problem.

To add a text ( I think you know this, but just to clarify )

```
<p id="IDHERE" style="font-size:50%">TextHere</p>
```

You can add more CSS code; just make sure that is small enough.

Comment: Now my square got reduced from small to tiny. :P